# Adventure Mode Stats Pareto Efficiency

Tags: mario-golf-super-rush

I've upgraded solely power at this point, and have broken a 320 yard drive at level 69, but I'm having some difficulties with the final fight. When I considered raising Speed to help in moving to the ball faster, I find that even with multiple levels my stat remains at 1.

I think this implies that the tracked stat values are actually negative, but are floored at 0. Presumably there is an overall level cap, how can I ensure that when I reach that cap, my stats are pareto-efficient. (There doesn't exist a build that's better or equal in all stats.)